# Qt zombies: Calling functions containing new with QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I'm trying to display a dynamically updating table using `QTimer` with a refresh rate of 1s. I'm calling the function `create_table` which in turn calles `create_title`. The code runs without complaints but tracking memory usage one finds that it keeps creeping up steadily till the program becomes unresponsive, or crashes.

```
void MainWindow::TableDisplay(QWidget *tab) {
    auto timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [refreshed_table_data, tab, this]() {
            auto tableView = create_table(tab, refreshed_table_data, "My table");
    });
    timer->start(1000);
}
```

The culprits seem to be the various `new` statements (indicated by comments in my code) which seem to create a fresh zombies/leak every time `QTimer` runs a loop.

```
auto create_title(const std::string &title, QWidget * widget) {
    auto tableTitle = new QLabel(title.c_str(), widget); // <-- new
    tableTitle->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    tableTitle->show();
}
```

```
auto create_table(QWidget * tab,
                  const std::vector<std::string> &v,
                  const std::string &title) {
    auto tableView = new QTableView(tab); // <-- new
    auto model = new MyModel(v, tab); // <-- new
    tableView->setModel(model);
    tableView->setStyle(new QProxyStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"))); // <-- new
    tableView->setHorizontalHeader(new QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal)); // <-- new
    create_title(title, tab);
    tableView->show();
    return tableView;
}
```

One solution could be to have the pointers initalized by `new` defined as member variables of `MainWindow` so that they are defined only once. But if I'm calling several such timed-functions, it would quickly become cumbersome, even more so when one considers there are rendering elements such as the line `new QProxyStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"))` etc which would then need to be accorded the status of member variables.

I tried wrapping the `new` statements with `QScopePointer`s but unfortunately the instances get destroyed right after `create_table` goes out its scope, resulting in no rendering of the table graphics.

What's the right way of writing `create_table` without creating zombies?

Comment: Normally, you'd just update the model with new data. If your model/view relationship is set up correctly, views would automatically refresh themselves. It doesn't make sense to create a brand new set of UI components every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question itself: Your `createTable` method could call `QTimer::singleShot` to schedule an update one second later.

```
auto create_table(QWidget * tab,
                  const std::vector<std::string> &v,
                  const std::string &title) {
    ...
    QTimer::singleShot(1000 /*ms*/, this /*context*/, [this, tab, v, title]() {
            create_table(tab, v, title);
    });
    return tableView;
}
```

However, as Igor noted, this whole approach seems backwards. The model should update itself, preferably event-based but if it has to poll external resources, it may have to use a timer itself.

Setting an entirely new model for a view is very expensive (because the view has to create everything from scratch) and can have annoying side-effects on the GUI side.